# Xming how to disable listening on network interfaces?

Tags: xming

I've searched and searched, but I can see no option to restrict Xming from listening on all my network interfaces.

I'd like to set Xming to listen ONLY for X11 forwarding via SSH tunneling.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the description of the Xn.hosts file on [this page](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/trouble.php).

The file X0.hosts, which you will find in the Xming installation directory, defines which hosts it will allow connections from. The default is only to allow connections from the local host (assuming you did not override it further using the xhost program).

This restricts the hosts which it will allow connections from, but AFAIK won't actually stop it from listening on the all interfaces.

Note that X11 forwarding over ssh requires that the X server on the local machine is listening on the loopback adapter at least. After all the ssh client will have to establish a connection to the X server somehow.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41330/let-xorg-listen-on-tcp-but-only-to-localhost) might also be interesting.